# Modernizr thinks Android 2.3.5 browser has CSS Animation support

Tags: android, css-animations, modernizr, android-browser

I'm using Modernizr for fallbacks to CSS Animation but it seems to think that the browser in Android 2.3.5 has support for animations. This means that users get stuck on a page.

I setup a little webpage to test mobile device support. Despite a basic animation not working, the test still passed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('html').hasClass('cssanimations'))
    {
        alert('I have CSS Animation Support');
    }
});
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://daneden.me/2011/12/14/putting-up-with-androids-bullshit/), Android 2.3 supports animating one property at a time. Give that a shot? Here's [the test](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/animations.js?source=cc) in Modernizr suggesting that Android is crazy.